# Count possibilites for single crossovers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following problem. In my code 
I have arrays of size L. The entries are either 0 or 1 for all arrays. Lets set L=3 for an example. Three possible arrays are `(1,1,1)`, `(1,0,0)` and `(0,1,1)`. Now I want to know how many single crossovers are possible with `(1,0,0)` and `(0,1,1)` to form `(1,1,1)`. The answer would be one. For `(1,0,1)` and `(0,1,0)` to form `(1,1,1)` the answer would be 0, because I would need two crossovers. I am looking for an algorithm which does this for general L. (L is usually not larger than 9). So far I don't have any idea and that is why I have post this problem her but I will make an edit if I got one. Hope you can help me :)

Edit: The outcome can be of course not only 0 or 1 but also greater than 1.
Example: `(1,1,0,0)` and `(0,0,0,0)` to form `(0,0,0,0)` the outcome would be 2. (I can only take the last entry of the first array or the last 2 entries of the first array)

Edit 2: By single crossover I mean, that I can take the left/right side of the first sequence and the right/left side of the second sequence to form the given third sequence. `(1,1,0,0)` and `(0,0,0,0)` to form `(0,0,0,0)`  --> `0,0)` + `(0,0,` or `0)` + `(0,0,0,`

Answer (score 2):

Another way of interpreting the problem is as calculating the [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).  Here is a snippet to create a dictionary of all pairs of each Hamming Distance/crossovers.

```
from itertools import combinations

tuples = [(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1)]
crossovers = {k: [] for k in range(len(tuples[0]))}
for a, b in combinations(tuples, r=2):
    num_crossovers = sum(el1 != el2 for el1, el2 in zip(a, b))
    crossovers[num_crossovers].append((a, b))
```

After executing crossovers will be as follows

```
{0: [],
 1: [((0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1)), ((1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1))],
 2: [((0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0))]}
```

**EDIT:**

I missed that you were using numpy arrays instead of tuples, you could do

```
arrays = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]])
crossovers = {k: [] for k in range(arrays[0].size)}
for a, b in combinations(arrays, r=2):
    num_crossovers = sum(np.abs(a - b))
    crossovers[num_crossovers].append((a, b))
```

Comment: Okay, so I understand what you did there but at this point I don't see how it can help me? Hamming distance is also not the same as crossover. A single crossover does mean, that I take the left/right part of the first sequence and the right/left part of the second sequence and the outcome will be a given third sequence.

Comment: I see, I didn't catch what you meant by crossover although it sounded like Hamming Distance from the examples.