# Performance nested loop in numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

For performance reasons, I have started to use Numba besides NumPy. My Numba algorithm is working, but I have the feeling that it should be faster. There is one point which is slowing it down. Here is the code snippet:

```
@nb.njit
def rfunc1(ws, a, l):
    gn = a**l
    for x1 in range(gn):
        for x2 in range(gn):
            for x3 in range(gn):
                y = 0.0
                for i in range(1, l):
                    if numpy.all(ws[x1][0:i] == ws[x2][0:i]) and
                    numpy.all(ws[x1][i:l] == ws[x3][i:l]):
                        y += 1
                    if numpy.all(ws[x1][0:i] == ws[x2][0:i]) and 
                    numpy.all(ws[x1][i:l] == ws[x3][i:l]):
                        y += 1
```

In my opinion the `if` command is slowing it down. Is there a better way? (What I try to achieve here is related to a previous posted problem: [Count possibilites for single crossovers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029617/count-possibilites-for-single-crossovers)) `ws` is a NumPy array of size `(gn, l)` containing `0`'s and `1`'s

Comment: You realize this scales horribly with the size of `gn`...?

Comment: Yes sure, maximum size of l is 9 and a is always 2

Comment: Are you in Python 2 or 3?

Comment: python 3 using anaconda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the logic of wanting to ensure all items are equal, you can take advantage of the fact that if any are not equal, you can short-circuit (i.e stop comparing) the calculation. I modified your original function slightly so that (1) you don't repeat the same comparison twice, and (2) sum y over the all nested loops so there was a return that could be compared:

```
@nb.njit
def rfunc1(ws, a, l):
    gn = a**l
    ysum = 0
    for x1 in range(gn):
        for x2 in range(gn):
            for x3 in range(gn):
                y = 0.0
                for i in range(1, l):
                    if np.all(ws[x1][0:i] == ws[x2][0:i]) and np.all(ws[x1][i:l] == ws[x3][i:l]):
                        y += 1
                        ysum += 1

    return ysum


@nb.njit
def rfunc2(ws, a, l):
    gn = a**l
    ysum = 0
    for x1 in range(gn):
        for x2 in range(gn):
            for x3 in range(gn):
                y = 0.0
                for i in range(1, l):

                    incr_y = True
                    for j in range(i):
                        if ws[x1,j] != ws[x2,j]:
                            incr_y = False
                            break

                    if incr_y is True:
                        for j in range(i,l):
                            if ws[x1,j] != ws[x3,j]:
                                incr_y = False
                                break
                    if incr_y is True:
                        y += 1
                        ysum += 1
    return ysum
```

I don't know what the complete function looks like, but hopefully this helps you get started on the right path.

Now for some timings:

```
l = 7
a = 2
gn = a**l
ws = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(gn,l))
In [23]:

%timeit rfunc1(ws, a , l)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.11 s per loop


%timeit rfunc2(ws, a , l)
1 loop, best of 3: 39.9 ms per loop

In [27]: rfunc1(ws, a , l)
Out[27]: 131919

In [30]: rfunc2(ws, a , l)
Out[30]: 131919
```

That gives you a 50x speed-up.

Comment: What about using `jit` with `nopython=True`?

Comment: `njit` is equivalent to `jit(nopython=True)`

Comment: Oh, I actually get an error, when I try the code: `numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
Internal error:
NotImplementedError: No definition for lowering is(bool, bool) -> bool` What could be the reason?

Comment: The error occurs in the code line: `if incr_y is True:`

Comment: The code works, if I use integers instead of booleans, but I don't know why

Comment: What version of Numba are you using? I ran this using v0.29 on my machine.

Comment: ah okay, I had v0.25 and that was actually the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just "having a feeling" where your bottleneck is, why not **profile** your code and find *exactly* where?

The first aim of profiling is to test a representative system to identify what’s slow (or using too much RAM, or causing too much disk I/O or network I/O).

Profiling typically adds an overhead (10x to 100x slowdowns can be typical), and you still want your code to be used as similarly to in a real-world situation as possible. Extract a test case and isolate the piece of the system that you need to test. Preferably, it’ll have been written to be in its own set of modules already.

Basic techniques include the `%timeit` magic in IPython, `time.time(),` and a `timing decorator` (see example below). You can use these techniques to understand the behavior of statements and functions.

Then you have `cProfile` which will give you a high-level view of the problem so you can direct your attention to the critical functions.

Next, look at `line_profiler,` which will profile your chosen functions on a line-by-line basis. The result will include a count of the number of times each line is called and the percentage of time spent on each line. This is exactly the information you need to understand what’s running slowly and why.

`perf stat` helps you understand the number of instructions that are ultimately executed on a CPU and how efficiently the CPU’s caches are utilized. This allows for advanced-level tuning of matrix operations.

`heapy` can track all of the objects inside Python’s memory. This is great for hunting down strange memory leaks. If you’re working with long-running systems,
then `dowser` will interest you: it allows you to introspect live objects in a long-running process via a web browser interface.

To help you understand why your RAM usage is high, check out `memory_profiler.` It is particularly useful for tracking RAM usage over time on a labeled chart, so you can explain to colleagues (or yourself) why certain functions use more RAM than expected.

*Example: Defining a decorator to automate timing measurements*

```
from functools import wraps

def timefn(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def measure_time(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time()
        print ("@timefn:" + fn.func_name + " took " + str(t2 - t1) + " seconds")
        return result
    return measure_time

@timefn
def your_func(var1, var2):
    ...
```

For more information, I suggest reading [High performance Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449361595) (Micha Gorelick; Ian Ozsvald) from which the above was sourced.

Comment: These are all good **general** recommendations, but none are really applicable to this problem. For example, you can't use `line_profiler` inside of a numba function, nor can you call `time.time` in `nopython` mode. The original question was about improving the performance of a function (presumably already identified as a hot spot) that was coded in numba. Typically there, you have to have an intuition for what Numba can convert into high-performance llvm code and many of the general techniques do not work to figure that out.

Comment: @JoshAdel: I wanted to suggest to OP that one needs not guess where the bottleneck is, but can profile to know for sure. I tried to make the profiling options somewhat complete (even if not all would be applicable to OP's circumstance) for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Here's the chapter link in Google Books: https://books.google.com/books?id=bIZaBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false