# How to cache Flask-App-Builder views?

Tags: python, caching, flask, flask-appbuilder

I have a working Flask app with pretty extensive *SQLite* database (~100k entries). 
I'm struggling to bootstrap some ModelViews with **Flask-App-Builder (FAB)** in simplest way according to [docs](http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickhowto.html):

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):
  datamodel = SQLAInterface(MyModel)
  list_columns = ['col1', 'col2']
```

than enabling them like this:

```
appbuilder.add_view(MyModelView, 'Models')
```

It works fine. The problem is, every time I visit *list* view, it is generated from scratch - DB query, some FAB processing, template generation. And it is subjectively very slow (tens of seconds by wall clock; I'm not sure how to properly profile Flask application).

I think caching FAB views at some point may help speed up things, but I'm unsure how to go about it. For ordinary views I use **Flask-Cache**:

```
@app.route('/some_route')
@cache.cached()
def view_function():
    data = time_consuming_operation()
    return render_template('template.html', data=data)
```

**So, question:**

How one would use cache with FAB ModelViews?
Is there a way to speed up work of FAB ModelViews?

Thank you!

**Result**

Ok, after exploring FAB source I see that it is possible to redefine methods of ModelView or it's parent to get desired behavior (in my case - limiting query for List view and caching it with Flask-Cache). However it will take a good deal of code and that defies whole purpose of using FAB.
As a result I moved to **Flask-Admin**. It has simpler look and does not include for instance in-built authentication, but it works so much faster in my case with so little configuration - **it solved my issue**.

I still recommend to give FAB a try in case of small amount of data (~1000 entries) it is richer in features and it's further development might give us a really neat product.

By the way, still I haven't found a way to cache of FAB ModelView response, but for me for now this question is closed.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and rewrite your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I made some edits. Is formulation good enough now?

Comment: Usually on SO, @HardBite, one is expected to try himself, show what he did and then ask for SO's community's help. Thus, prior to your "How one would use cache with FAB ModelViews? Is there a way to speed up work of FAB ModelViews?" you're actually supposed to show what you did (based on your research on SO, Google, books, etc.).
BTW, profiling Flask is the same as profiling Python in General. You may look ay my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41069372/1656850

Comment: @boardrider thank you for remark. I'll edit my question as soon as will be able to devote some more time to it. Although It is my first question for over 2 yrs reading SO. One may presume that I do not ask questions unless I really can not find a solution or hint on a solution available. And one will be right (: Anyway after looking in FAB docs and source I see some ways to make it work faster and cache view methods, but it involves meddling with FAB pretty deeply. And that significantly reduces convenience of using this library.