# Performance of replacing elements in a list versus list comprehension

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension, disassembly, measurement

As user2357112 pointed out, the original performance test script didn't worked as expected by me. "after the first execution of s1, your list has no 1s in it, so no further executions of s1 and no executions of s2 actually take the x==1 branch."
The modified version:

```
import timeit
import random
random.seed(0)
a = [ random.randrange(10) for _ in range(10000)]
change_from = 1
change_to = 6
setup = "from __main__ import a, change_from, change_to"

# s1 is replaced for a simple for loop, which is faster than the original
s1 = """\
for i,x in enumerate(a):
    if x == change_from:
        a[i] = change_to
change_from, change_to = change_to, change_from
"""

s2 = """\
a = [change_to if x==change_from else x for x in a]
change_from, change_to = change_to, change_from
"""
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=s1,number=10000, setup=setup))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=s2, number=10000, setup=setup))
```

This script replaces every occurrences of 1 to 6, and the next run every occurrences of 6 to 1. And so on. The result is:

```
7.841739330212443
5.5166219217914065
```

Why is the list comprehension faster?

And how should one figure out this kind of question?
boardrider's comment looks interesting, thanks.

The following python version is used:
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Since I didn't got a detailed answer I tried to figure it out.

If I represent the simple for loop with this function:

```
def func1(a):
    for i,x in enumerate(a):
        if x == 1:
            a[i] = 6
    return(a)
```

and disassemble it, i got the following:

```
func1:
  7           0 SETUP_LOOP              48 (to 51)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (enumerate)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                34 (to 50)
             16 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             19 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
             22 STORE_FAST               2 (x)

  8          25 LOAD_FAST                2 (x)
             28 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             31 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             34 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       13

  9          37 LOAD_CONST               2 (6)
             40 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             43 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             46 STORE_SUBSCR
             47 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   50 POP_BLOCK

 10     >>   51 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             54 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is simple. It iterates through the a, and if it finds the value 1 it replaces it with 6 with STORE_SUBSCR.

If I represent the comprehension variant with this function:

def func2(a):
    a = [6 if x==1 else x for x in a]
    return(a)

and disassemble it, I got the following:

```
func2:
  7           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x00000000035731E0, file "<file_path>", line 7>)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('func2.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             12 GET_ITER
             13 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  8          19 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is shorter than the previous. However it starts with a code object loading. The func2 has the following code constants:

```
>>> func2.__code__.co_consts
(None, <code object <listcomp> at 0x00000000035731E0, file "<file_path>", line 7>, 'func2.<locals>.<listcomp>')
```

and the listcomp code object looks like this:

```
>>> dis.dis(func2.__code__.co_consts[1].co_code)
          0 BUILD_LIST               0
          3 LOAD_FAST                0 (0)
    >>    6 FOR_ITER                30 (to 39)
          9 STORE_FAST               1 (1)
         12 LOAD_FAST                1 (1)
         15 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
         18 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
         21 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       30
         24 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
         27 JUMP_FORWARD             3 (to 33)
    >>   30 LOAD_FAST                1 (1)
    >>   33 LIST_APPEND              2
         36 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
    >>   39 RETURN_VALUE
```

So essentially the two implementation performs the similar steps. The main difference is that the comprehension version replaces the FOR_ITER with a CALL_FUNCTION.

From this I should see why the list comprehension is faster, but I don't.
So my original question is still on:

Why is the list comprehension faster?

Comment: List comprehensions in general are faster than a for-loop. This order of magnitude seems like what you would expect.

Comment: "I would think that in-place replacement would be faster for large lists than creating a new list with a list comprehension." - what, were you thinking the extra allocation would be expensive? This is CPython, highly dynamic and completely JITless. Almost everything is more expensive than allocation.

Comment: @user2357112 Since you seem to know the answer, would you mind offering it? I'm interested in knowing the reason for this and I'm sure others are too.

Comment: Also, note that after the first execution of s1, your list has no 1s in it, so no further executions of s1 and no executions of s2 actually take the x==1 branch.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll try to come up with some real measurement. However what I originally taught was that list comprehension produces an entirely new list, and copies the values from the original list. And the replacing just a few values seems bit less work. Clearly this simplistic view of comprehension is false. I'll should dig deeper in the topic. Thanks

Comment: `how should one figure out this kind of question?` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051553/performance-nested-loop-in-numba/41069372#41069372